# How to reinstall/upgrade android OS in my phone

Tags: android

I purchased MicroMax A60 mobile phone which was not provided with any PC suite. This phone in-built comes with Android V2.1 Eclair OS. I searched manufacturer's website and found that they are not providing any user tool to re-install/upgrade android OS. Is there any free third party tool to re-install/upgrade my android OS?

Comment: Should be on Android Stack Exchange. http://android.stackexchange.com/ Edit: Or you already asked it there with a different name. Please do not make duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try googling "MicroMax A60 cyanogenmod". You will find a few hits.

Comment: What do you mean by cyanogenmod?

Comment: cyanogenmod is a custom android rom that you can install on most devices.